# How do I change the direction of wood texture for other objeccts?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

Normally I would make textures for wood that would go into X or Y direction because when I rotated objects the texture would look like the seat in this picture. Rather than create textures for each direction of wood, I want to know if I could just change the direction of objects so that they have the same pattern as the armrests on my chair and how to do it.

[image: Adirondack]

This is how the nodes are set up.

[image]

Comment: You could try to add a separate material to that part of the chair and use the mapping node to rotate the texture

Comment: I can do that but was wondering if I could just use one material and then change the orientation of another object so that it has the same effect. Also, I forgot to mention that I want a diagonal material but rotating it in the Mapping node does not seem to work.

Comment: Well, instead of using  procedural material, you could UV unwrap your object and paint your textures in anyway that you need